# I'm having some problems with displaying my data in browser's console

Tags: javascript

I want to show the information of "widndow.console.log..." part in my browser's console as: "path 1 is A/B/C" using this code, but I think something's wrong with my first or second function because in the console I get: "path 1 is undefined"... can someone help?

```
var makePath = function(b) {
    var x;
    return function(path1) {
        x=path1+b;
      }
}
var main = function() {
    var path1 = makePath ("/");
    path1("A");
    path1("B");
    path1("C");
    window.console.log("path 1 is" + path1());
}
```

Comment: Your code works as written when you fix the typo in `console`. But that's probably not what is intended, since var path1 will contain a function. So logging it gives: `path 1 isfunction(path1) { x=path1+b; }`, while I suspect you want to log `x`.

Comment: sorry I just edied my last line of code it should be: "window.consol.log("path 1 is" path1() )

Comment: Seems like there are a whole bunch of users working on this same problem in the past couple of days. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957828/question-about-javascript-closures-and-paths https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970559/javascript-closures-function?s=2|0.0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting x every time you call path1, so only the last letter passed will be shown. Since you call path1() without passing a letter, you get `undefined/`

I think you might be trying to do something like below code, which adds the letter you pass it to the previous result instead of overwriting it.

```js
var makePath = function( path_header ) {
  var path = [];
  return function( path_chunk ) {
    if ( path_chunk ) path.push( path_chunk );
    return path.join( '/' );
  }
};
var main = function() {
  var path1 = makePath ("/");
  path1("A");
  path1("B");
  path1("C");
  window.console.log("path 1 is " + path1());
};
main();
```

Comment: If this is the same exercise as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957828/question-about-javascript-closures-and-paths the `path_header` is supposed to go between the items, not just at the front. `A/B/C`

Comment: yes as I wrote in my question that I want it to be like "A/B/C" but this way I will get "/ABC"

Comment: That wasn't entirely clear to me as your code only gave you A/ B/ and C/ . I've changed the code. This did make it a bit trickier, if the result has to be `A/B/C` instead of `A/B/C/`. Not sure if using the makePath function is part of the assignment or something, to isolate the scope of x.